# Proving that Hermitian conjugate operator is unique

Tags: linear-algebra

A very basic question:

Considering the $\Phi : Hom(U) \rightarrow M_{n}$ isomorphism  between linear operators on vector spaces, and square matrices and the fact that Hermitian conjugate of an operator represented by matrix $A$ is $A^*$, isn't it sufficient to say that the Hermitian conjugate of an operator is unique because Hermitian conjugate of a matrix is unique? (which is easy to show)

Comment: You can do that. Of course you need to prove that, once you have fixed an orthonormal basis, *any* Hermitian conjugate of an operator is represented by the same matrix. And so the Hermitian conjugate is unique. I don't think that it is *easier* than a more abstract proof, but for sure it is more computational and has its advantages.

Comment: Why is it easier to show this for matrices?

Comment: It's merely a matter of personal taste, nothing serious, I was just wondering why was the uniqueness proved using linear functionals instead of this (in my textbook). This just seems easier.

Comment: It is mainly a matter of taste, as you say. Some authors have a delight in presenting coordinate-free proofs, some others like to do exactly the opposite. Both approaches have advantages.

Comment: That's what I thought, but one can never be too sure when learning. Thank you!